# Extra beats per measure on one staff

Tags: notation, rhythm, musescore

I'm new to stack exchange, so here goes...

How is this possible: Some sheet music I'm trying to use, written in 6/4 time, is written for piano, and, of course, includes both treble and bass staffs. In the treble staff, the notes and rests add up to 6 quarter notes, as they should - but in the bass staff, they add up to 9 quarter notes. How is this played (or rather, what is it equivalent to)?

[image: Example of what is explained above.]

If you can't see the image, this measure of the treble staff has a quarter rest, a quarter note, two eighth notes, and three more quarter notes. The same measure, this time in the bass staff, has a whole note, a half note tied with a quarter note, and another half note.

And if anyone would *happen* to know, can I replicate this in MuseScore? If so, how?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't use MuseScore, but it looks like you want https://musescore.org/en/handbook/voices

Comment: @replete Respectfully disagree, as this one's a little more complicated (there's no rest over the note). However, OP should consider checking out that question for sure.

Comment: @replete Well, I think it just comes down to opinion really on how close "dupe" requires. Anyway, it doesn't matter now, because you wrote a great answer, which I gave +1.

Comment: I don't agree it's a dupe -- this example is a very poorly edited bit.  As replete answered, there should be a rest in both staves.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The notation could look something more like this:

[image]

This makes the intent clearer, however shortcuts such as in your example are common.

Comment: I hope they aren't too common -- it's really sloppy!

Comment: Thanks! Makes perfect sense, seeing it as two separate voices.